# Attack Bonus question for Monsters with multiple attacks from multiple weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, attack

When a monster wields multiple weapons, and can attack multiple times with each, how do I alter (or should I leave) the given attack bonuses on each type of attack on the enemy's stat block?

Take, for example, monster [Asura, Upasunda](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/asura/asura-upasunda):

> Melee: *Mwk Longsword* +20/+15/+10 (1d8+6/19-20), *Mwk Spear* +19 (1d8+6/x3), *Mwk Kukri* +19 (1d4+6/18-20) OR 6 slams +18 (1d4+6)

I'm pretty sure the OR means on a full round action I can choose the slams or all the others, but say I choose the weapon attacks to make a full round attack, after the first 3 attacks with +20/+15/+10 does the spear then get the +19 and ignore the usual attack bonus negative progression because its a different hand/weapon? Or what happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mixing weapon and natural attacks is a mess. Fortunately, it is not what happens in this example.

Here you see 2 full attack options: one for 4-hand multiweapon fighting (iterative attacks from main hand, single attacks at highest BAB from off hands, no penalty for multiweapon fighting due to racial ability) and one for all-natural full attack (several natural attacks at highest bonus each). *And it looks like this creature has 6 hands, but only wields weapons in 4 of them.*

Yes, the spear ignores negative progression because it is used in different hand.

Ever-helpful [Pathfinder SRD link](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack), just in case.